# Python select() behavior is strange

Tags: python, linux, unix, io

I'm having some trouble understanding the behavior of select.select.  Please consider the following Python program:

```
def str_to_hex(s):
    def dig(n):
        if n > 9:
            return chr(65-10+n)
        else:
            return chr(48+n)
    r = ''
    while len(s) > 0:
        c = s[0]
        s = s[1:]
        a = ord(c) / 16
        b = ord(c) % 16
        r = r + dig(a) + dig(b)
    return r

while True:
    ans,_,_ = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[])
    print ans
    s = ans[0].read(1)
    if len(s) == 0: break
    print str_to_hex(s)
```

I have saved this to a file "test.py".  If invoke it as follows:

```
echo 'hello' | ./test.py
```

then I get the expected behavior: select never blocks and all of the data is printed; the program then terminates.

But if I run the program interactively, I get a most undesirable behavior.  Please consider the following console session:

```
$ ./test.py
hello
[<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb742f020>]
68
```

The program then hangs there; select.select is now blocking again.  It is not until I provide more input or close the input stream that the next character (and all of the rest of them) are printed, even though there are already characters waiting!  Can anyone explain this behavior to me?  I am seeing something similar in a stream tunneling program I have written and it's wrecking the entire affair.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Off-topic, but `def str_to_hex(s): return ''.join(('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s))` ;-)

Comment: @slowdog: How about `import binascii; binascii.hexlify(s)` instead? Writing your own hex conversion function is silly when an extremely fast one already exists.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Oh, cool! I still underestimate the amount of "batteries included".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `read` method of `sys.stdin` works at a higher level of abstraction than `select`. When you do `ans[0].read(1)`, python actually reads a larger number of bytes from the operating system and buffers them internally. `select` is not aware of this extra buffering; It only sees that everything has been read, and so will block until either an EOF or more input arrives. You can observe this behaviour by running something like `strace -e read,select python yourprogram.py`.

One solution is to replace `ans[0].read(1)` with `os.read(ans[0].fileno(), 1)`. `os.read` is a lower level interface without any buffering between it and the operating system, so it's a better match for `select`.

Alternatively, running `python` with the `-u` commandline option also seems to disable the extra buffering.

Comment: And this _is_ the answer to the OPs problem.

Comment: Though, another way to handle the Python buffering issue to to simply do a no-parameter read, which should read everything currently available.

Comment: There are several ways to disable Python's buffering, outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering. It's generally not necessary to disable buffering, and I wouldn't expect it to be preferable in this case (I don't see how It'd be beneficial for simple stream processing). Great answer though.

Comment: Thanks!  This explains a lot.  The no-parameter reading wasn't an option; in the actual use-case, I'm launching a subprocess over SSH and the two scripts are using the subprocess's stdin and stdout to communicate.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is very helpful for a problem I found very perplexing! slowdog, unfortunately, unbuffered input doesn't work with "paste". @Omnifarious, "no-paramater read" is not so simple.  I managed to work out the details and posted them here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750135/need-character-by-charter-keyboard-input-that-interacts-well-with-paste-and-ansi

Answer (score 1):

It's waiting for you to signal EOF (you can do this with Ctrl+D when used interactively). You can use `sys.stdin.isatty()` to check if the script is being run interactively, and handle it accordingly, using say `raw_input` instead. I also doubt you need to use `select.select` at all, why not just use `sys.stdin.read`?

```
if sys.stdin.isatty():
    while True:
        for s in raw_input():
            print str_to_hex(s)
else:
    while True:
        for s in sys.stdin.read(1):
            print str_to_hex(s)
```

Which would make it appropriate for both interactive use, and for stream processing.

Comment: This isn't the answer to the OPs problem.

Comment: Using `sys.stdin.read` seems preferable to using `select.select` to me. Sure you can work around `select.select`, but it seems like a pretty ugly approach to me.

Comment: sys.stdin.read blocks; the point of using select.select is to be able to wait for one of two different input sources.

Comment: Ah, I see. From your question that wasn't obvious to me (although I guess it should have been since you were using `select.select` in the first place).